# How can I generate a random day of the year in a specified year quarter with python?

Tags: python, pandas, random

Let's suppose in a pandas dataframe I have for a certain record:

```
x.index.quarter
```

is 3

I need to generate an integer from 1 to 365 as day of the year, that would belong to the same quarter.

How does pandas decide the year quarter? Is there a mathematical formula? Does it depends only on the months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbering the days of the year from 0 to 364, you can find the quarter interval with

```
q = 3 # Quarter index from 0 to 3
q_length = int(365/4) # 91, length of the quarter 
d_min = q*q_length
d_max = (q+1)*q_length
```

Then find a random day of the year within that quarter using:

```
d = np.random.randint(d_min, d_max)
```

Just change `q` for `x.index.quarter`.

Comment: Yup, day 0 in Python indexing!

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment, cause I thought I wrote something stupid, so python actually starts quarter one with date 0, I somehow thought quarters corresponded to seasons, now I understand, they're literal quarters. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an approximate solution (I don't know if python has any quarter handling function - taking into account leap years). However given the generic nature of the question, following may be useful assuming 3 months or 90 days a quarter:

```
import random
n=3 #quarter at hand
start=(n-1)*90 + 1 #starting point for current quarter (adding 1 to offset 31 days)
end=n*90 -1 #end point for current quarter (substracting 1 to stay in range of the quarter without doubt)
random_day=random.randint(start,end)
```